# How are values taken from the BORDER_CONSTANT option

Tags: opencv

I need to pad an image using the BORDER_CONSTANT option, and also takes a Scalar value where you specify what you want the values of the paddings to be, I wanted to know what is the sequence of the values, e.g. is it (Top,Right,Bottom,Left) or some other sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using `copyMakeBorder`

> C++: void copyMakeBorder(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int top, int bottom, int left, int right, int borderType, const Scalar& value=Scalar() )
>
> Python: cv2.copyMakeBorder(src, top, bottom, left, right, borderType[, dst[, value]]) → dst

In *value* you specify the color of the padding (when using `BORDER_CONSTANT`) which will be the same on top, bottom, left and right.

> value – Border value if borderType==BORDER_CONSTANT.

```
Mat3b img; // Your original image
...
Mat3b padded1;
copyMakeBorder(img, padded1, 10,    10,  10,   10, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0,255,0));
//                           ^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^^
//                           top bottom left right

// Now padded1 has a green border of 10 pixels around the original image.
```

If you really want to set different padding colors for top, bottom, etc, you can do as:

```
Mat3b img; // Your original image
...

Mat3b padded2;
copyMakeBorder(img    , padded2, 10, 0, 0, 0, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(255,0,0));
copyMakeBorder(padded2, padded2, 0, 10, 0, 0, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0,255,0));
copyMakeBorder(padded2, padded2, 0, 0, 10, 0, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0,0,255));
copyMakeBorder(padded2, padded2, 0, 0, 0, 10, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(255,0,255));

// Now padded2 has different padding color in each side.
```

---

**UPDATE**

Usually you just want to create some padding for `CV_8UC1` images. So simply:

```
Mat3b img; // Your original image
...

Mat1b gray;
cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

// Add a black padding (of 10 pixels) around the image
Mat1b padded3;
copyMakeBorder(gray, padded3, 10, 10, 10, 10, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));
```

Comment: what does it mean when you write Scalar(0,255,0,0). does it pad the top,left and right with 0s bottom with 255? 

I get that you put Scalar(255,0,0) to specify each channel of RGB, but I should mention that my image is greyscaled. 

Sorry I read your answer again, this probably answers my question, I'll try that.

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan  If your original image is grayscale, i.e. `CV_8UC1`, or equivalently `Mat1b`, than just write `Scalar(0)` to have a black padding, `Scalar(255)` for a white padding, or `Scalar(some_value_from_0_to_255)` to have a gray padding.

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan just to be clear, you set the _size_ of the padding with `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` values. With `Scalar(...)`, you specify the _color_ of the padding, so `Scalar(...)` will have 1 argument for 1 channel matrix (grayscale), and 3 arguments for 3 channel matrix (e.g. rgb).