# Using openCV Blur with BORDER_CONSTANT option?

Tags: opencv, padding

I am trying to creating a blurring function that can take all possible padding options. However for BORDER_CONSTANT you also need to provide the color, i.e. the numbers that you want to pad your image with. In opencv's documentation of blur I don't see an overload of function blur that takes padding and the color value. Does anyone know how to overcome this?

One thing I thought about doing was padding the image first and the blurring some region of interest with no padding at all, although I can't find a way to do that.

The question referred to was asked by me, so basically I would know if this was a duplicated. This question was relating to cv::blur which also handles padding, however does not have an option of adding the border values for BORDER_CONSTANT. I was asking if anyone knows a workaround.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are values taken from the BORDER\_CONSTANT option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605181/how-are-values-taken-from-the-border-constant-option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I assumed in the original post is correct. If anyone cares for a solution here goes:

```
copyMakeBorder(image_in_mat, image_in_mat, r, r, r, r, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(myNumbers));
ROI = Rect(r, r, w, h);
image_in_ROI = image_in_mat(ROI);
blur(image_in_ROI, image_out_mat, Size(blockSize, blockSize), Point(-1, -1));
```

where r is the radius you want to pad with; w,h are width and height of original image; myNumbers - the color you want your padding to have; image_in_mat  - input image.

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the source code for `blur`, you'll find out that, when the `borderType` is `BORDER_CONSTANT`, the value for the border will be `Scalar(0,0,0,0)`.

Just a quick reverse-engineering... If you create a white (255) `CV_8UC1` matrix and `blur`with a `3x3` filter with `BORDER_CONSTANT`, you'll see that the result is:

[image]

In the angles you'll get: `(255*4 + 0*5) / 9 = 113`, on the border you get `(255*6 + 0*3) / 9 = 170`. This demonstrate the the padding is of zeros.

Sample code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1b img(5,5,uchar(255));
    blur(img, img, Size(3, 3), Point(-1, -1), BORDER_CONSTANT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks this was what I figured. I was wondering if there was a way to use BORDER_CONSTANT and not use Scalar(0,0,0,0). I wanted to use something like Scalar(myNumbers). I found in openCV 2.4 documentation that if my given image is a ROI of some larger image then the bounds of that larger image are used as padding. I am not sure if this is kept in opencv 3.1 if it is, I believe I can overcome my issue by first padding the original image and the blurring the ROI with no padding at all.